# how to break text by each letter in each line when screen gets too small of responsive web page? Html Css

Tags: html, css

I want to break text by each letter when the screen size gets very smaller. But my css code in breaking word into combination of letters instead of by each word. Please help me knowing how to do this?

> What I want is:
>   [Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTXZ2.png)
>
> but result is
>   [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xpjC.png)

```
    
   <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
        .responsive {
          max-width: 100%;
          height: auto;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
        <body style="color: black;/* word-wrap: break-word; */word-break: break-all;">
    
        <h2>Responsive Images</h2>
    
        <p>If you want an image to scale down if it has to, but never scale up to be larger than its original size, use max-width: 100%.</p>
        <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
    
        <img src="https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNQvyq5Td0dEqQRqodTpCDxctpjh4Q:1580199153874&q=site+image&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMt_bJ7KXnAhUpQEEAHTcvDo4QsAR6BAgKEAE&biw=1366&bih=625#" alt="Web" class="responsive" width="600" height="400">
    
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: `writing-mode: vertical-rl;
text-orientation: upright;`

Comment: Thanks but I didn't  work.

Comment: In what situation is your component/browser that you need it to be like that? I'm asking because your window is at the smallest possible. In reality you will never have a user in that view for it to be necessary to support that. If you do like Matana say you need to target a specific media query, and that ties it back to my first question, in what situation do you need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply CSS in a media query screen less than 50px or you may change to the specific screen size you want.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 50px) {
 body{width: 10px;}
}
```

Comment: thank you so much this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Could you please explain how did you get it that adding width=10px will be the solution? Actually I am newbie in web development and learning these concepts to build clear understanding but its still unclear to me how adding width property in media query worked. I will be grateful to you.

Comment: if you are not using word-break and having width 10px the content will be out of the division. word-break is needed which is already applied by you but characters break at each line would help when you apply width 10px. Moreover, you want in small screen size that's why the css is applied in media query.

Comment: I got it.Thank you once again. I cannot up-vote right now I need 15 reputations to do so.